# Is there a theological link between the views of Cassian and Pelagius and Arminianism?

Tags: reformed-theology, free-will, arminianism, pelagianism

During the fifth century, John Cassian claimed that the initial steps to salvation were in the power of each individual, unaided by grace.  He reacted against Augustine’s view of the irresistible power of grace and predestination.  Circa 414 Augustine of Hippo strongly affirmed the existence of original sin, the impossibility of a sinless life without Christ, and the necessity of Christ's grace. <sup>1</sup>

Pelagius, a Romano-British theologian, was known for his emphasis on human choice in salvation and his denial of original sin.  He believed in mankind’s good nature and individual responsibility for choosing asceticism, stressing the freedom of human will. <sup>2</sup>

Pelagianism was a school of thought that taught that the human will was capable of spiritual good without the aid of God’s grace, and that sinless perfection was possible in this life.  This was supported by Nestorius.

Augustine and Jerome were chief critics of Pelagianism, and it was condemned by church councils in A.D. 418 and 431 (Council of Carthage).  From Pilgrim Theology, pp.468 & 470, Michael Horton, Zondervan, 2011

Fast forward to 1610 when five articles of faith based on the teachings of Jacobus Arminius were published in protest against Calvin's doctrines relating to divine sovereignty, human inability, unconditional election (or predestination), particular redemption, irresistible grace, and the perseverance of the saints.  The Synod of Dort was convened to examine the views of Arminius, and in 1620 a response was published, rejecting the Arminian position and presenting the Calvinistic position.

Although the church was quick to denounce the ideas of Cassian and Pelagius (excommunicating the latter), have some of their ideas on free will and man's ability to accept the salvation offered by God, filtered down through the centuries to influence resistance to the Reformed view of the depraved nature of humanity and God's sovereign power in the matter of election and predestination unto salvation?

Is there a theological link between the views of Cassian and Pelagius and Arminianism?

Sources:

<sup>1</sup> [New Advent: John Cassian](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03404a.htm)

<sup>2</sup>[Wikipedia: Pelagius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelagius)

Comment: Maybe the link is [synergism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergism) which is not necessarily Pelagian, thus frequently labeled [Semi-Pelagianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-Pelagianism).

Comment: Will check out that article a.s.a.p.  It's all a bit of a minefield, spiritually speaking!